# Can't update my windows 10 (No updates showing)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-v1803

I'm trying to update Windows 10 v1803, but whenever I try to update via Windows Update, it states: You're up to date.

I've searched many websites and can't find any solutions. I've tried restarting Windows Update Services.

Any solution will be really appreciated, as I've tried every potential solution found so far, but still can't update my system.

Comment: I have no clue why this is on hold for the reasoning listed, as it's a duplicate at worst... This is a known issue... update via the _Update Now_ button on [Microsoft's Download Windows 10 site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)